# wasserstein distance on color swatches

Tags: image, numpy, colors, scipy, histogram

I try to calculate relative color distances between `RGB` color swatches of my data set, with three of my color swatches of my test set.
Thus, of the color swatches are numpy arrays with shape `1,6,3`, and `RGB` values are normalized.
To compare swatches,  I convert each color swatch into a color histogram, using `np.histogram`, through flattening `np.flatten()` the arrays. Finally I compare the histograms with each other using the built in `scipy.stats.wasserstein_distance` method. However, distances repeat each other and it all seems off. 
I was wondering if someone could give me a hint on how to approach this. I think that the error lies in flattening of the arrays, but I am not quite sure on how else, I can convert RGB colors to compare against each other.

Test-1.jpg - 1x5px! -
https://ibb.co/Fsg7Mkd 
Test-2.jpg - 1x5px! -
https://ibb.co/0jz4Zk1 
Test-3.jpg - 1x5px! -
https://ibb.co/SB0fhFh

```
from scipy.stats import wasserstein_distance as wd
import numpy as np
import cv2


def compute_histogram(image, nr_bins):
    hist = np.histogram(image, bins=nr_bins, range=[0, 255])
    return hist

# data swatches to measure the test swatches against
data_sw = np.array(
                  [[[225, 254, 239],
                   [145, 212, 167],
                   [116, 186, 137],
                   [ 91, 162, 115],
                   [ 72, 143,  98]],

                  [[ 97, 165, 214],
                   [211, 234, 230],
                   [ 61, 195, 182],
                   [ 77,  92,  75],
                   [145, 157, 136]],

                  [[  1,  35, 220],
                   [ 12,  20, 142],
                   [105, 159, 177],
                   [ 11,  85, 130],
                   [ 15,  39,  49]]])


# the test Files stored locally
test_files = ['Test-1',
              'Test-2',
              'Test-3']

# n bins
n_bins_ = 6

# distances from each test file to each swatch
dict_distances = {}

#computation of distances
for tst_name in test_files:

    # load testfile locally
    tst_fl = cv2.imread(tst_name+'.jpg')[0]

    # store distances temporarily
    temp_dist = {}

    # loop over the data swatches to compare test swatches to
    for i,d_sw in enumerate(list(data_sw)):

        # make 1-D
        curr_testsw = tst_fl.tolist()
        curr_datasw = d_sw.tolist()

        #create histogram
        test_hist = compute_histogram(curr_testsw, n_bins_)[0]
        data_hist = compute_histogram(curr_datasw, n_bins_)[0]

        #calculate the distance between histograms
        distance = wd(test_hist, data_hist)

        # put into temp dict using the indices of data as keys
        temp_dist[i] = distance


    dict_distances[tst_name] = temp_dist

print(dict_distances)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post what you have tried?

Comment: Yes, I edited the file

Comment: I looked through the paper called ' A Metric for DIstrubutions with Applications to Image Databases' from ' Yossi Rubner Carlo Tomasi , and Leonidas J. Guibas from Stanford (1998). Which relates to what I try to do. But the be honest, I am not quite math literate yet, to understand everything - I keep working on it.

Comment: Can you provide the 3 JPEGs please?

Comment: should be there

Comment: Please correct your code so it at least runs! You can't initialise a Numpy array like that. You haven't imported `cv2` and your links to the images are mis-labelled.

Comment: You are right - my apologies, important lesson learned -> never edit your code in stack overflow. It should work now.

Comment: hi - were you able to run it?